# Affine Transform Question

Tags: graphics, geometric-transform

I set up these:

```
T1 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {0, 0}}];
T2 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {1/3, 0}}];
T3 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {2/3, 0}}];
T4 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {0, 1/3}}]; 
T5 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {2/3, 1/3}}];
T6 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {0, 2/3}}];
T7 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {1/3, 2/3}}];
T8 = AffineTransform[{{{1/3, 0}, {0, 1/3}}, {2/3, 2/3}}];
```

Then I did this:

```
g1 = Graphics[{
   Rectangle[],
   Red, GeometricTransformation[
    Rectangle[], {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]
   }]
```

Which worked nicely. My next thought was to apply the transformations to g1.

```
g2 = Graphics[{
   Rectangle[],
   Red, GeometricTransformation[g1, {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]
   }]
```

But I got an error "Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive." What am I not understanding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *g2 just produces the same image g1 again*

The new rectangles in `g2` are not visible because they are all red. Change `Red` to a random color and they become visible:

```
g2 = Graphics[{Rectangle[], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   GeometricTransformation[g1[[1]], {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> *What I want to do is apply the eight transformations to g1 again, to produce the second step of a Sierpinski Carpet.*

```
g1 /. r : Rectangle[_] :> {Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   GeometricTransformation[r, {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[Partition[Nest[# /. r : Rectangle[_] :> 
     {Hue[RandomReal[]], GeometricTransformation[r, {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]} &,
     g1, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

> *I got an error "Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive."*

The first argument of `GeometricTransformation` should be a graphics **primitive** (such as `Disk`, `Rectangle` etc.). So `GeometricTransformation[g1[[1]], {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]` works without complaint.

```
g2 = Graphics[{Rectangle[], Red, 
      GeometricTransformation[g1[[1]], {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry, this just produces the same image g1 again. What I want to do is apply the eight transformations to g1 again, to produce the second step of a Sierpinski Carpet. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @David, please see the update.

Comment: Absolutely awesome response! Thanks, this is so helpful.

Comment: @David, great question. Thank you for the accept.